# How to write a div into a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a quick question. I'm not sure exactly what this is called, but how do you write a div into a div? 
Example, I want to create a simple game that stays on the same page. When a button is clicked to move on to the next part of the game, the original div will be erased and a new one put on top of that.

So, lets say I have a div called "start" and another called "option 1". Option 1 would be hidden, while start is displayed as the home page. When you click a button on the "start" div, it writes the "option 1" div over that, erasing the first div.

My HTML code:

```
<div id="start">
<button class="button" onclick="swordsman()">Choose Swordsman</button>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
function swordsman()
{
document.getElementById("start")writeDiv.id="option 1"
}
```

And that is where I am stuck, I don't know the code to replace a div with another div. It's purely a guess.

I am new to JavaScript, so excuse my stupidity.

Comment: You can replace the contents using `innerHTML` -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML

Comment: Nick, thanks, although I didn't know how to write the div into the html with that. I didn't know the exact way to code it.

Comment: @Timby Look at BenjaminRH's answer.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML` like so:

```
function swordsman() {
    var otherDiv = document.getElementById("option-1").outerHTML; // Get the option 1 div
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = otherDiv; // Replace the contents of the start div with the option 1 div
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an syntaxerror

```
  document.getElementById("start")writeDiv.id="option 1"
```

should be
      document.getElementById("start").writeDiv.id="option 1"

but i think there is no function "writeDiv", but you can use the innerHTML atribute:

```
  document.getElementById("start").innerHTML ='<div id = "option 1"></div>';
```

look also for jQuery, DOM handling will be much easier ;)

you can check your code for syntaxerros by using browsers javascroipt console